# ¿Como obtener el id del objeto en el arreglo?

Tags: php, symfony

Al hacer un `dump` del formulario:

```
        $data = $form->getData();

        dump($data->getUsers()->toArray());die;
```

Consigo este `array`:

```
EventoController.php on line 162:
array:1 [▼
  0 => App\Entity\User {#2179 ▼
    -id: 20
    -nombre: "zetaaa"
    -apellido: "zeta"
    -email: "zeta@zeta.com"
    -password: ""
    -role: "ROLE_USER"
    -fecha: DateTime @1612260841 {#2187 ▶}
    -foto: null
    -eventos: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#2183 ▶}
    -salas: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#2176 ▶}
  }
]
```

**¿Como saco solamente la ID del array?**
En este caso seria 20

Comment: ¿Qué mostraría un `dump($data->getUsers()`;? No uso Symphony pero me parece que sería mejor trabajar con el objeto `User` y usar su método propio para obtener el id, que sería, supongo `getId()`, sin necesidad de convertirlo a array, mareando los datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano no se puede, te envía todo. Y necesito sacar solo la id del array, gracias :D

Comment: Intenta hacerlo así: `$data->getUsers()->toArray()[0]->id`

Comment: @Marcos gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta corta es:

```
$data->getUsers()->toArray()[0]->id
```

#### Explicación:

Dado que `$data->getUsers()->toArray()` devuelve un arreglo con un valor, para acceder al primer elemento en el arreglo podemos hacerlo así:

```
$array = $data->getUsers()->toArray();
$user = $array[0]; // Obtenemos el primer valor en el arreglo
```

Luego dado que el primer valor es un objeto del tipo `App\Entity\User`, para acceder al `id` de dicho objeto, podemos hacerlo así:

```
$array = $data->getUsers()->toArray();
$user = $array[0]; // Obtenemos el primer valor en el arreglo
$id = $user->id; // Obtenemos el id del usuario
```

Lo que es igual a (*pero quizás no tan fácil de leer*)

```
$id = $data->getUsers()->toArray()[0]->id;
```